# Can not run debugging in VC++ 6.0 installed in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I followed instruction ([How Do I run Visual C++ 6 IDE on Windows Vista or higher?](https://superuser.com/questions/459396/how-do-i-run-visual-c-6-ide-on-windows-vista-or-higher)) to install VC++ 6.0 in Windows Ultimate 7 (x32).  It can build the project but I can't debug it in the IDE.  The "Excute" menu under Build is grayed out.  Nothing happens when I presse F5 to run the program.

What is preventing debugging in the IDE?  How to enable the Execute menu?

Thanks,

Mike C.

Comment: Did you attach the process to Visual Studio.

Comment: Ramhound, Thanks for your comment.  I was referring to the "execute" menu in the VS.  My compiled program executes well outside the IDE environment, but I can't debug it within the IDE because the "Execute" menu is grayed out.